# Fury of Dracula 3rd ed. - Bats Token and Defeated Hunter

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In Fury of Dracula 3rd edition, if a hunter who has a bats token under him/her gets defeated, does the bats token travel with the hunter to the hospital?

If yes, since hospitals are adjacent only to the attached city, does this mean that Dracula actually helps the hunter by moving him/her to the attached city, thus sparing the hunter from having to spend the action to move to the attached city themselves? Or is the effect of the bats token suspended until it is more useful to Dracula (like in case of hunter already being delayed, or hunter being in a city with a fog token, see Rules Reference)?

Answer (score 1):

The rules say:

> The bats token functions as a reminder that Dracula can move
>   that hunter to an adjacent city during that hunter’s next action.

When the hunter is defeated and moved to another city, it isn't of the hunters own volition, but it is a must and doesn't cost the hunter an action.

then:

> For the purposes of game rules and effects, if a hunter is in
>   a hospital space, he is adjacent to and not in the location
>   attached to that hospital.
>
> While on a hospital space, the only actions a hunter may
>   perform are a modified version of either the supply or move
>   action, as follows:
>   » Supply: The hunter may perform a supply action to draw
>   one item card. He always draws one item card but cannot
>   draw an event card.
>   » Move: The hunter may move from the hospital to the city
>   attached to that hospital.

So when the hunter wants to do any action in the hospital (eg supply or move) Dracula must move him to an adjacent city, which is, in this instance, the city attached to the hospital.